# Text Shadow not showing

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a button, where the font is bold but it also uses a text-shadow to make the text more readable. For whatever reason the text-shadow is not appearing when its added to the CSS, though in photoshop it makes a dramatic difference using the same values.

[Here's the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bmuaT/1/)

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The shadow is there, but it's **so faint** that it's nigh impossible to perceive, especially with a relatively low alpha value and when superimposed on a background with a similar hue.

I'm going out on a limb and guessing that in Photoshop, your text shadow has a layer style that causes it to have a different effect on the underlying background color. You may need to play around with the eyedropper tool and tweak the alpha value in your text shadow, in order to achieve something that better matches your Photoshop comp.

Comment: Try playing with an extreme color... [like red](http://jsfiddle.net/bmuaT/2/).  When you get the effect you want, change it back to a more suitable color.